# How bad is this cam wear?

Tags: dodge, camshaft, viper

This is from a 96 viper, with a hydraulic roller cam, having .600" of lift. This cam has about 2000 miles on it, but mostly hard track miles

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to tell from the images whether or not the cam is wiped, but if there are only 2000 miles on the cam, then that is *a lot of wear*, even if it's all track miles.

If you are really worried about it, you need to pull the cam (yah, I get it ... in Viper, easier said than done), then measure it with a micrometer to determine wear, plus give it the feel test. Run your fingernail over the lobes along the axis and see if you feel any ridges. Without measuring it, you're not going to know the extent of the wear.

Another thing you can do is look at your lifters. Check the rollers for wear. Are they in good shape? If the rollers move fine without any wobble or deflection, plus the rolling surface is in good shape, things might just be okay. I don't know that I'd trust it, though. Wipe out your cam lobes and wipe out your engine. There'd be too much metal hanging out in the pan to be doing your engine any good.

Comment: I can get my finger down the lifter bore and the lobe feels smooth. It looks more like a discoloration due to heat, but I'm not confident in that assertion. The rollers on the lifter look pretty good also. I rolled them back and forth in my hand and I don't feel any catch.